# Ubuntu server with high load on virtualbox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I have a an Ubuntu 12.04 x64 image, which i use for different customers on different virtualisation systems.
Current customer uses VirtualBox and the system has a high load on it and response very slowly.

top output:

```
top - 09:27:58 up 4 days, 10:19,  1 user,  load average: 0.78, 0.87, 0.87
Tasks: 118 total,   2 running, 116 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.4%us,  0.8%sy,  0.0%ni, 90.4%id,  3.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  4.3%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32174396k total,  4213080k used, 27961316k free,   347136k buffers
Swap:  2096124k total,        0k used,  2096124k free,  2108644k cached
```

Here is an output of "ps aux"

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  24336  2260 ?        Ss   Jul10   0:06 /sbin/init
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10   0:02 [kthreadd]
root         3  5.8  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10 371:31 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jul10   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7  1.8  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10 118:43 [migration/0]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10   0:00 [rcuob/0]
root        10  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10   0:00 [rcuob/1]
root        11  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10   0:00 [rcuob/2]
root        12  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10   0:00 [rcuob/3]
root        13  1.5  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10  98:01 [rcu_sched]
root        14  0.4  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10  26:19 [rcuos/0]
root        15  0.3  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10  25:16 [rcuos/1]
root        16  0.3  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10  22:59 [rcuos/2]
root        17  0.3  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10  22:25 [rcuos/3]
root        18  2.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10 132:56 [watchdog/0]
root        19  1.5  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10  97:19 [watchdog/1]
root        20  1.4  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10  93:34 [migration/1]
root        21  6.8  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10 432:20 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        22  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10   0:00 [kworker/1:0]
root        23  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jul10   0:00 [kworker/1:0H]
root        24  0.4  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10  27:45 [watchdog/2]
root        25  0.6  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10  42:32 [migration/2]
root        26  1.5  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10  97:07 [ksoftirqd/2]
root        28  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Jul10   0:00 [kworker/2:0H]
root        29  0.2  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10  15:43 [watchdog/3]
root        30  0.7  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10  48:06 [migration/3]
root        31  1.3  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Jul10  87:48 [ksoftirqd/3]
```

The guest has 32gb RAM and 4 Cores assigned. CPU is a Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2609.
I know the host is a windows system.

Output of iostat:

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.31    0.01    3.67    6.67    0.00   89.35

Device:            tps    kB_read/s    kB_wrtn/s    kB_read    kB_wrtn
scd0              0.00         0.00         0.00         48          0
sda               0.99         5.57        11.70    2129835    4477412
```

Noticeable is that ksoftirqd and other processes have a high cpu usage/load. 
Any ideas what it is causing it?
The VM itself works on other systems very well, so i guess its a problem with the Host/VM-Host configuration.

Comment: load average shown in your output is load average: 0.78, 0.87, 0.87 for respectively 1,5,15mins

Comment: How much RAM does the host have?

Comment: if it is slow with those numbers, I would guess disk-io as a typical problem area

Comment: Just get them off VirtualBox and save yourself and your customer a lot of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Server communicates with the devices attached to it through IRQs (interrupt requests). When an interrupt comes from a device.If ksoftirqd is taking more than a tiny percentage of CPU time, this indicates the machine is under heavy interrupt load.

check logs with lspci

Check this link for reference: https://askubuntu.com/questions/7858/why-is-ksoftirqd-0-process-using-all-of-my-cpu